# How to show newly added books in iBooks on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, books

I use an iPad mini 4 as an ebook reader to read PDF books. I don't know if it's because of my stupidity or else, I feel iPad is many times harder to use as an e-reader than an android tablet, it has caused me many headaches in doing things as simple as transferring or syncing books. I often have the thought of ditching the iPad and getting an android tablet instead but my thrifty nature always wins.

I have many books on iPad, and I use collections to manage books in the iBooks app. A problem has harassed me for a long time: when I add a new book to iTunes, sync it to iPad, and try to move it to a collection, it is very hard to find the newly added book on iPad. It is buried in a list of hundreds of books. There is no "not in any collection" category. I searched Google many times for a simple solution but without success.

Where do I find newly added books in iBooks app?

Comment: You could try a third-party app, I use PDF-Expert for my ebook collection. It is much better than Apple Books app imo, and you can transfer PDFs via WiFi too https://apps.apple.com/nz/app/pdf-expert-7-pdf-editor/id743974925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what iOS version you're at but there is a sort by feature in Books.app in iOS 12. Also, most of the collections also allow you to sort. I normally put them in Want to Read for quick access.

> [image]
>   [image]